# How to avoid input keyboard shortcut stealing by websites in chrome extension develpment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm working on browser extension development and insert an input form in a modal for the extension, but I found website shortcut key event has higher priority than input key press, so I cannot get the input letter. For example, if press letter **L** in TikTok, it will trigger like a video instead to add **L** to the input text field, any solution to avoid this and capture input press first?

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener('keydown', fn, true)` to be the first target of the event dispatching process, then call event.stopPropagation() inside fn.

Comment: yes, @xOxxOm your solution works, sample like below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code works as @wOxxOm mentioned above

```
function untilDocumentReady() {
    function fn(e: KeyboardEvent) {
       var key = e.key;
       console.log("You pressed a key: " + key)
       e.stopPropagation()
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', fn, true)
}
```

or

```
function untilDocumentReady() {
   ...

    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      var key = event.key;
      console.log("untilDocumentReady - You pressed a key: " + key)
      event.stopPropagation()
    }, true);
  })
}
```